Can you force Chrome to install an app to desktop? (even if it's not a PWA)
There are some apps I'd like to install to desktop which are not PWAs (and I'd like to force "tabbed" PWA mode via Chrome flags) - like Slack, Jira.
I like the idea of reusing the existing Chrome engine for multiple desktop apps rather than installing each electron powered client and running a separate Chromium instance for each app - plus tabbed PWAs are fantastic and a much better experience for apps like Slack, Jira, etc - which electron does not support.
Can this be done?
EDIT:
Looks like it can be, but with limited customization

Doesn't allow you to force tabbed mode - which is a bit of a dealbreaker. Wonder if I could write a Chrome extension to inject a manifest.json

Does this answer your question? Can you force install a website as PWA on Chrome?

Not quite. The term "PWA" and the concept of a web application you can install to desktop is used interchangeably. That question asks if a non-PWA website can be made into a PWA (which requires certain things - like a service worker, offline support, etc). I just want to install a non-PWA as an app without PWA functionality.

It does answer your question. It tells what is required in order to be a PWA, and it notes that you can pin shortcuts to sites that are not PWAs in most modern Chromium browsers.

I could be wrong but the answers on that question seem to describe creating a shortcut to a website - which will open up in your default browser as a normal tab rather than "install" the website as a native app in the same way you can with a PWA (with features like looking it up from your start/spotlight/app menu and having it open up in an independent browser context).
